# EJB in a non managed bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

What is the best/recommended way to pass a stateless EJB  to a non managed bean(thread) in a Java EE application ? I've considered sending a reference via the constructor so far.

Answer (score 1):

As of CDI 1.1 (Java EE 7), you can use the `CDI` class to get a reference to the current CDI container.

EJBs are also exposed as CDI beans. So, you just have to get a reference to your EJB's local interface:

```
CDI.current().select(YourEJBLocalInterface.class).get();
```